# Inserting new record by stored proc

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to insert/update record with a specific stored-procedure which performs some business-logic on new record values. I can do this by trigger to ignore new record from directly to be inserted and pass new record values to my stored-procedure to perform appropriate action for passed values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, once you're working within a trigger, you need to perform all of your actions as part of the body of the trigger, rather than calling other code in e.g. a stored proc.

This is because the inserted and deleted "logical tables" only exist within the context of the trigger.